# Mountain Lion: Heroku update gives weird error message

Tags: macos, heroku, osx-mountain-lion

I looked and looked, but cannot find what's going on. I am having trouble with Heroku and the toolbelt in particular. So I wanted to try updating it and try to do

$ heroku update

and I get

```
Error: undefined method `error' for Heroku::Updater:Module (NoMethodError)
```

What's going on here?

Comment: `heroku --version`returns 2.23.0 for me, and I get this when I try to run `heroku update`:  "!    `heroku update` is only available from Heroku Toolbelt. !    Download and install from https://toolbelt.heroku.com" I expect that is because I've installed it as a gem. Other commands like `heroku logs` work fine. Perhaps try installing as a gem if you haven't?

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue.  I have toolbelt installed.  But heroku update doesn't work, but all other commands seem to.  Just recently updated to Mountain Lion....

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem after I updated to Mountain Lion, but now everything is working fine.
I did like below.

1. Remove the heroku toolbelt

   rm -rf /usr/local/heroku
   rm -rf /usr/bin/heroku
2. Remove the heroku gem

   gem uninstall heroku

   I got a message which gem to uninstall, so I chose 'all'
3. Install the heroku toolbelt, again.
4. heroku update -> works fine

Hope this will work.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. Note that just reinstalling the toolbelt, did NOT work (OSX Lion).

Comment: Same for me on OS X Lion. This solves the problem without hurting any heroku related application.

Comment: If you are using rbenv maybe you want to remove `.rbenv/shims/heroku` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I managed to bust update in 2.23.0 (sorry).  So if you run into this you should be able to just skip directly to downloading and reinstalling the toolbelt.  This should overwrite any old stuff (and afterward you should have a working update again).  Sorry for the inconvenience.